# I need to select certain digits from a floating number. Is it possible? if yes, how?

Tags: floating-point, vhdl

An example:
0.6345482635429

I want to select digits from (10^-6) to (10^-9) as in select (263) and save it. I applied this in Matlab. I am trying to apply it in VHDL. The example is in decimal perspective rather than the floating point format im using.

Is it possible to convert the floating number to decimal and then select the required number/digits from the decimal format?

I am applying a 32-bit floating point format. I dont know how to select the same range of digits for a floating number in VHDL.

I did not try anything yet since i originally do not know how to do so.

Thank you!

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you are having a _string_ which represents a number. Or do you have a floating point number (result of computation) from which you want to have those values?

Comment: floating point number, a result of computation

Comment: do you want it rounded or not?

Comment: no i do not want it rounded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible for a 32-bit floating-point object to preserve the information needed to determine the digits of arbitrary numbers with nine decimal digits (except for a degenerate floating-point format with a one-bit exponent or with a two-bit exponent and no sign bit).

Floating-point formats represent mathematical numbers, not numerals. Especially, binary formats do not represent decimal numerals. With care, it is possible to use floating-point to compute the decimal digits that would result from various mathematics, but this requires knowledge and good design. Often, it is a bad idea, and there is a better solution. For VHDL, it is likely a very bad idea. For nine-digit numbers using 32-bit floating-point, it is impossible, as the information present in a normal 32-bit format is insufficient to preserve nine decimal digits, let alone compute with them.

The IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary floating-point format has 24-bit significands. 2<sup>24</sup> = 16,777,216, which is not even eight digits. If the number represented is around .634 as in your example, the high bit of the significand corresponds to 2<sup>−1</sup>, and the low bit corresponds to 2<sup>−24</sup>, which is about .0000000596046. This is not fine enough to preserve digits after the seventh decimal place.

If you wanted to use multiple 32-bit floating-point objects to represent the number or the digits, some extended-precision techniques might work. However, it is quite likely there is a better solution, perhaps something that directly represents a string of decimal digits.

Comment: I agree with your statement about floating point numbers, but you can always convert it to a string and perform string manipulations to extract the requested information. If that information is  meaningful in one way or another is a complete different question which depends on the problem where we have no information about.

Comment: @kvantour: The problem is not converting the value to decimal, it is that the desired information is not present.

Comment: The desired information is present. The binary number, with 32 bits, can be represented decimal with about 100 digits (`2^-24` has about that many decimal digits). In C, `printf` could convert the float to a string which can then be manipulated. Whether all those decimal digits have any actual information is questionable.

Comment: Example, the number presented by the OP is `0.6345482635429` but the decimal representation of the nearest floating point number is `0.63454826354289994849722233993816189467906951904296875`, when you take this number as a character string, you quickly extract the information requested by the OP.

Comment: But as indicated earlier, it is true that any digits about 10^-7 are actually generated by all the bits which represent all the decimal digits from 10^0 till 10^-7, so the decimal digit representing 10^-9 actually is a number which is a consequence of all the other digits.

Comment: @kvantour: (a) 2^-24 has 24 digits after the decimal point, not 100. It is .000000059604644775390625. (b) Read the first sentence of the answer: “It is not possible for a 32-bit floating-point object to preserve the information needed to determine the digits of **arbitrary** numbers with nine decimal digits…” The problem is not to find the digits in some number that happens to be a consequence of the floating-point format; the problem is to find the digits in a desired number.